# Does it matter where I hit enemies when shooting?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Should I aim for the head when firing to kill enemies faster or does this have no effect at all, and I shouldn't bother?

Recent games like Skyrim do not have this differentiated damage system, so shots to the head are the same as shots to the body and limbs, is it like this on Mass Effect 3?

Comment: I sure hope that aiming to the head affects.

Comment: For the record bow headshots actually do double damage in Skyrim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! Aim for the head (or head-analogues)!

One of the loading screen tips alludes to this directly, but there are half a dozen other clues that you get bonus damage depending on where you shoot - the equipment which "increases headshot damage by X%", for one, and the multiplayer kill achievement for another.

Perhaps most viscerally, scoring a solid headshot on a humanoid opponent will cause their helmet to explode in a brief fountain of gore.

So aim for the head!

Comment: Alternately, Aim for the legs! You'll cripple 'em and they won't run so fast! (Handy for melee opponents like husks!)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'musing an Eviscerator shotgun. I basically just point at them and they die regardless. >:D