# Does "no scoping" do less damage then scoping

Tags: mass-effect-3

Specifically in Sniper Rifles, I have noticed that when I "no scope" a target (normally at close range) it appears that the damage I do is significantly less then when I'm scoping a target. This has put me in the habit of actually scoping in no matter the distance.

When I "no scope", I normally aim for the chest, being the easiest spot to hit. I decided I would actually make an effort to see if my suspicions were correct. So far it would seem that it definitely does less damage compared to scoping a target for a chest shot as they die easily in one shot, "no scoping" a chest shot usually takes 2 shots with a Black Widow on Bronze difficulty against weaker troops.

I did see the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53722/does-it-matter-where-i-hit-enemies-when-shooting) that explained the benefits of headshots versus everything else. Which even "no scoping" a headshot will cause a death to the smaller enemies but definitely not to stronger troops that I easily one shot while scoping.

I'm hoping someone else has noticed this besides me or knows if there is something else afoot?

Comment: Edited the last line; unfortunately, we can't really predict Bioware's intent here (nor do we allow such questions at all). Otherwise, an interesting question!

Comment: @ravendreamer yah i figured that would be a stretch anyway.

Comment: Sounds like your question answered itself.

Comment: I definitely noticed this too, when I shoot from the hip I do much less damage even though it looks like a direct shot.  Its very obvious with my infiltrator, when I scope I can 1 shot kill normal enemies no matter where I hit, but when I shoot from the hip they don't die.

Comment: I wonder if it's just a question of accuracy - it's a lot harder to see where your shots land from the 3rd person view.

Comment: @ravendreamer i wouldve agreed with you at one point but when i can shoot someone in the foot or hand while scoping in and kill them, then shoot someone while no scoping there is a very noticable difference in damage

Comment: @Kotekzot you are correct on that but i have never encountered a game where no scoping does less damage then scoping in.

Comment: @Paralytic TF2?

Comment: never played team fortress 2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tested this today by using my asari vanguard. I used stasis bubble to freeze two cannibals next to each other and then shot one in the midsection without scoping and the other while zoomed in. The zoomed shot did four bars of damage while the non-zoomed shot did two bars. I think it's safe to say that **zooming results in more damage**. I used a Viper I without any mods for the test.

Answer (score 1):

In my test on single player/insanity unscoped sniper shots dealt 85% of scoped damage.